# Call EntityManager inside a form

Tags: symfony-2.1

We can easily custom the powerful Symfony2 form component with an [entity Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
// ...

$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
));
```

Is there a way to inject a method using a custom Entitymanager (UserManager in this case) instead? I am thinking that in the case of long queries, it might be interesting to have the option to use custom methods from an EntityManager instead?

Comment: Is this a 2.0 or 2.1 question? Plenty of changes in the form component.

Comment: This is a Symfony 2.1 question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each form can be described as a service in service container so you can specify any dependencies from any other services. I would say it's a good idea to encapsulate queries inside repository/usermanager instead of using them inline. Ihmo symfony version does not matter in this case.